# bracket can be removed in this scala code?

Tags: scala

I don't understand this code below. firstly, read is a method, looks like it has two parameters, don't understand the rest of them. Can you please break down each part and show its meaning ? especially why it is using {..} ?

```
read(resultsIn)({previousResult => xx}, () => {})
```

The source code is [here](https://github.com/gosubpl/akka-online/blob/master/src/main/scala/pl/gosub/akka/online/recursive/least/squares/RecursiveLeastSquaresStage.scala), line 39. have a little modification for learning purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you happen to know where read is defined, can't say if it is getting curried or taking in a implicit param. I don't feel like pulling it right now. Can you search for the definition if you have it pulled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over the [Akka Stream API page](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/index.html) I see that a number of classes in the akka.stream.stage package have a `read()` method with the following signature.

```
final def read(in: Inlet[T])(andThen: (T) ⇒ Unit, onClose: () ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

So this `read()` takes three parameters curried into two parameter groups. The 1st parameter group has only one parameter which is a value of type `Inlet[T]`.

The 2nd parameter group takes two parameters. The 1st is a function that takes a value of type `T` and returns nothing (`Unit`). The 2nd is a function that takes no input and returns `Unit`.

Therefore, in the code you've posted, `resultIn` must be of type `Inlet[T]` (for some specific type `T`), `previousResult` is a variable receiving a value of type `T` (as previously defined), `xx` is the code that processes (or ignores) the input and produces nothing (or if it has a result it is ignored), and `() => {}` is just a dummy do-nothing function supplied just because there has to be something there as the 3rd parameter.

Curly braces `{}` simply enclose and define a code block. They're often optional but they're needed when multiple lines of code need to be evaluated as a unit.

Comment: Yes. `{}` is an empty code block. It does nothing and returns `Unit`.

Comment: for first parameter , method is looking for (T)=>Unit, then why this will work, {previousResult => xx}  ?

Comment: `xx: Unit` becomes `{ xx; () }` by a conversion called "value discard". People like to turn on the warning for that. Some prefer to write `previousResult => { xx(); () }`. I also prefer `() => ()`.